# Are any of the other mutant characters in Legion based on comic characters?

Tags: marvel, x-men, legion

The TV show *Legion* has as its protagonist David Haller, based on [the character of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(Marvel_Comics)) from *X-Men* comics. It also features

> the Shadow King, again based on [a comics character of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_King)

However, I can’t find any obvious comics mentions of the other mutants in the show:

- Sydney Barrett
- Cary and Kerry Loudermilk
- Ptonomy Wallace
- Melanie Bird
- Oliver Bird
- Rudy
- The Eye

Were any of them based on existing comics characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPOILERS:

The are strongly hinting that David's father is in fact, Professor X, same as the comics. They both showed Professor X's wheelchair (with fancy X wheels) in a flashback, as well as address David's father as being a very powerful mutant telepath who fought the Shadow King at some point. No one else in Season 1 is a direct adaptation.

From Bustle.com "As creator Noah Hawley told Variety, he wants to evoke the X-Men without basing Legion on their most famous characters. "Obviously it’s a sort of origin story for David, but none of the other characters that I’ve surrounded him with are from the comics. It’s sort of an invented world," he explained.

Comment: True, although I was asking about the other mutants who we actually see in the show — we only really get to see a wheel that might belong to Charles Xavier.